# jSwing - making button run different methods

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jspinner

I'm working Java in NetBeans and trying to figure out a way to make jSpinner that depending on which button is pressed it runs 2 different methods. Like run up() when up button is pressed and down() when other one is. I can't figure out a way to achieve this effect.

Comment: You are looking for this: https://coderanch.com/t/344182/java/JSpinner-arrow-listener

Answer (score 0):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)//Could be keyReleased or keyTyped as well
{

    if (e.getKeyCode()==38)//38 is code for up button
    {
            up();
    }

    else if (e.getKeyCode()==40)//40 is code of down button
    {
            down();
    }
```

}